# My acer H235H's headphone jack on the back doesn't work

Tags: display

My acer h235's headphone jack on the back doesn't work! I want to use headphones while playing my xbox, and the monitor will not accept them.

Comment: Try plugging in the headphones before turning on the monitor. (The speakers in the display do work, right? If not you need to fix that first.)